# How can i get the seconds out of the chronometer?(Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, get, var, seconds, chronometer

Im trying to get the seconds out of the chronometer, but it will not work properly."

```
private var mSeconds = 0    
private fun updateChrono(){
        if(mChronoRunning){
            mSeconds = mSeconds +1
            tvChronoSeconds.text = mSeconds.toString()
        }
    }
```

The function above should count every second, but it counts randomly an just every 2nd second."
This is the Chronometer:

```
private fun startChrono() {
        chronometer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +mChronoStopTime
        chronometer.start()
}

private fun pauseChrono() {
        mChronoStopTime = chronometer.base -SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        chronometer.stop()
}

private fun resetChrono() {
        chronometer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        chronometer.stop()
}
```

Is the declaration of the var wrong?
Is the finction wrong? has anyone an idea how to do it right. Thank you!!!"

Answer (score 0):

okay:what i have done so far: i made a new var
 "var mElapsedSeconds = 0L"
and put it in the function.i took the elapsedRealtime, minus the base and divided it by 1000.   it works with a short delay. maybe it helps someone!!!

```
 private fun updateChrono(){
    if(mChronoRunning) {
        mElapsedSeconds = ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mChronometer!!.getBase()).toLong()/1000);
        tvChronoSeconds.text = mElapsedSeconds.toString()
    }
}
```